# Issues converting API Response to JSON Object

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to usse `NSJSONSeriallization.JSONObjectWithData` to convert NSData to a JSON Object, my current code is:

```
let response = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

The var `receivedData` is 1013 bytes and contains a JSON response from an API.

If convert my NSData response to a string with this line of code instead of the previous:

```
let response = NSString (data: receivedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Using Xcode Debugging we can see that `response` as a string is:
[image]

And here is a cleaner view of that JSON string:

```
{
  "id": "373198",
  "result": {
    "registrationId": 742098068,
    "imageUrl": "/templates/images/user.gif",
    "external": false,
    "clientCode": "",
    "settings": null,
    "firstLogin": false,
    "type": null,
    "fromSite": null,
    "city": "",
    "sessionToken": "1457206061819919",
    "username": "buffettidemo",
    "postalCode": null,
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "permissions": null,
    "role": null,
    "gender": "",
    "specialBonus": null,
    "verifyPhone": null,
    "autocashout": null,
    "wizardFlags": 1,
    "lastName": "Demo",
    "enableMail": true,
    "extType": null,
    "companyName": null,
    "extId": null,
    "country": "",
    "paypalAccountEmail": null,
    "console": 2,
    "authorizationProfile": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "email": "adriano.tamburo@gmail.com21",
    "javaClass": "guardian.dto.UserAdaptor",
    "language": null,
    "numInvitation": 0,
    "region": null,
    "enablePhone": true,
    "registerDate": "1426693995000",
    "verifyMail": null,
    "id": 80447,
    "firstName": "Buffetti",
    "salesFee": null,
    "website": null,
    "dateBirth": "1426693995000",
    "taxCode": null,
    "quotesOrders": null,
    "permissionApp": null,
    "address": null,
    "authorizationExpired": false,
    "vatNumber": null,
    "mobileNumber": null
  }
}
```

My problem is, back to using this line of code:

```
let response = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

That my dictionary object `[string:AnyObject]` has zero entries:

[image]

Comment: Showing values there might be also a case of the debugger not able to show the correct value. Have you tried to log it? I tried your case and it works with your json as a file

Comment: First check whether the json is a valid json by using an online json validator!

Comment: @EridB I have not tried to log it, what do you mean by logging though, like "print()", I am not familiar with Swift logging

Comment: Yes I mean `print("\(response)")`

Comment: @EridB you were right man, a simple print(response) worked for me. the debugger was not able to show the correct value. If you want to answer the question I will award you the answer, might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a simple test by grabbing your response and putting it a file and loading it on **Playground**, seems to work. And also I don't notice any trouble with your response as I also validated it with a **JSON Validator**.

### Playground output

[image]

### Solution

Sometimes **Xcode Debugger** is messed up, so please try to log your response which is the most correct way if the debugger is not working